# How can I add a material to terrain?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var terrain = GameObject.Find("Terrain");
var termat = terrain.GetComponent<Material>();
termat = (Material)newterrainmat;
```

This does nothing no errors it's just not replacing the current terrain material with the newterrainmat.
I want to replace the current terrain material with the newteraainmat material.

I tried this now :

```
var terrain = GameObject.Find("Terrain");
var terraincomponent = terrain.GetComponent<Terrain>();
terraincomponent.materialTemplate = (Material)newterrainmat;
```

but it does nothing. Not giving errors but does nothing.

Comment: You're re-assigning the variable instead of changing the property. Try something like `terrain.getComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = newterrainmat;`

Comment: @Roope Terrain don't have MeshRenderer or any Renderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Roope said, `You're re-assigning the variable instead of changing the property`, do something like this:

```
var terrain = GameObject.Find("Terrain");
terrain.materialTemplate = (Material)newterrainmat;
```